# How to set fragment transitions to not overlap in styles.xml?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-5.0-lollipop, android-styles, android-transitions

To avoid fragment transitions from overlapping I used to set them to false just before I start my fragment's transaction. Like this

```
fragA.setAllowReturnTransitionOverlap(false);
fragA.setAllowEnterTransitionOverlap(false);
```

I came across an article that suggested to keep these in the `styles.xml` file to achieve the same effects across all fragments, but unfortunately I'm not able to set it in `styles.xml`

styles.xml(v21)

```
<item name="android:fragmentAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">false</item>
<item name="android:fragmentAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">false</item>
```

The "false" gets error-coded and says "cannot resolve symbol false".
What am I doing wrong?

[image: Pic of the above error]

Comment: What happens when you remove "android:" from the `name`?

Comment: @Sufian it throws an error while compiling. 
`Error:(3, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'fragmentAllowEnterTransitionOverlap'.`

Comment: Okay, what happens when you write `<item name="android:fragmentAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">@bool/valTrue</item>` and you've declared a bool named "valTrue" in your XML (see this - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Bool)

Comment: The correct styles declarations are  <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item> and
        <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>

Comment: using `@bool/valFalse` which has to be defined to `false`as well fixes the error, but it seems to have no effect. Calling the 2 methods in the Kotlin code has no effect for me as well, the transitons always overlap...